# Kendo UI Web - Drop-down list, different background color on each list item.

Tags: css, kendo-ui

I am playing with Kendo UI Web and finding ways to customise it with specific needs.
From my [JS bin](http://jsbin.com/anefoh/1/edit) I've simply added Kendo UI drop-down control with sample list items of which their background needs to be rendered with respective colors.

I've spent some time inspecting elements to alter its style but have yet to found a solution to control each list item. Does anyone have an experience with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one easy part and one difficult part. The easy is getting the background the difficult is making it look nice.

Easy, define a template for rendering each list item:

```
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    <div style="background-color: #= text #;">#= text #</div>
</script>
```

And then define your ComboBox as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#combobox').kendoComboBox({
        template : $("#template").html()
    });
});
```

but this is likely to do not be as nice as you want since before the `<div>` from my template there is a `<li>` introduced by KendoUI and unless you want to start playing with it, you might consider just displaying a color square with the item color.

You can do something like:

Start defining a CSS for the color square:

```
.ob-patch {
    margin: 4px 6px 0 0 !important;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

then the template for each item would be:

```
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    <div>
        <div style="background-color: #= text #;" class="ob-patch">&nbsp;</div>
        #= text #
    </div>
</script>
```

and the combobox initialization:

```
$('#combobox').kendoComboBox({
    template: $("#template").html()
});
```

Your JS Bin modified with this approach [here](http://jsbin.com/uneyel/2/edit)

**EDIT:** If you want that the background of the input gets the color of the selected item, you should use:

```
function setColor() {
    var val = this.value();
    this.input.css("background-color", val);
}

$("#combobox").kendoComboBox({
    template : $("#template").html(),
    dataBound: setColor,
    change   : setColor
});
```

Where the `change` event handler sets the value of the `input` from the option selected and `dataBound` event handler does it for the initial value.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Although it might look ugly getting the background, that is the requirement that I have to deal with. I tried again with your sample but the background rendering covers up the text. I want the outcome to be similar to the bottom list except the behavior that loses background when selected. Updated [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/uneyel/5/edit)

Comment: Is not covering the text it is simply that you removed the text. The template should be `<div style="background-color: #= text #;">#= text #</div>` (`#= text #` is twice, one for the background color and another for the text). See it here http://jsbin.com/uneyel/7/edit

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. Last thing I would like to know is how to keep the background color even when selected. It looks like selected item loses its background. Thanks again.

Comment: You mean once it has been selected and the list closes?

Comment: Yes. When list closes, selected item should keep the background.

Comment: Probably you can but it's a little tricky since what you choose is the text and that's what Kendo UI copies to the input. So you need to intercept the change event and restyle the input field. Hopefully this works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35129/discussion-between-onabai-and-seong-lee)